# RestUI: The used authentication method is not allowed on this route

Tags: authentication-authorization

The following works on three sites but doesn't work on one. I've restored the site from the backup of another site, and this works, until it doesn't work the next day. I've reinstalled modules.

I make the following POST request:

```
POST /node?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/hal+json
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Ruby
Authorization: Basic <authstr>
Connection: close
Host: <domain>
Content-Length: 215

"
<- "{\"_links\":{\"type\":{\"href\":\"https://<domain>/rest/type/node/article\"}},\"title\":[{\"value\":\"2024-03-15 Test\"}],\"body\":[{\"value\":\"\\u003cimg src='' alt='' /\\u003e\",\"format\":\"full_html\"}],\"type\":[{\"target_id\":\"article\"}]}"
```

where `<authstr>` and `<domain>` are my reasonable values. I'm getting `<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>`.

with message:

```
 "{\"message\":\"The used authentication method is not allowed on this route.\"}"
```

What is wrong?

I am using:

- HAL 1.0.3
- HTTP Basic Authentication 9.5.11
- restui 8.x-1.21
- RESTful Web Services 9.5.11
- Drupal 9.5

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe it...

The problem was that I created a `/node` Page, with content: `<script>window.location = '/some-redirect'</script>` and assigned that as the front page. This is perfectly reasonable behavior. And it broke a POST route, with the error ^ described in the question! I'd say this is a bug in Drupal. Deleting the page that does javascript redirect, fixed this issue.

What is also important is that `/node` is the default homepage route, so you may inadvertently do something on that page, breaking REST. I'd recommend not using `/node` at all, other than for REST POST'ing.